Larger possible chain of closed subspaces in the dual of a Banach space
In this question, is demonstrated that a separable space can have a chain (ordered by inclusion) of closed subspaces with uncountable many subspaces.
My question is the following. If $X$ is an infinite dimensional Banach space and $\mathrm{dens}(X)=\alpha$ (where $\alpha$ is an infinite cardinal and $\mathrm{dens}(X)$ is the smallest cardinality of a dense subset of $X$), is there a chain $L$ with $\alpha$ closed subspaces of $X'$ endowed with the weak*-topology (where $X'$ is the dual of $X$)? I'm also interested to know if, for every $x\in L$, the set $\{y\in L\mid x<y\}$ has $\alpha$ elements (or at least there are "many" $x$ with that property. Analogously, I would be interested in the case that $\{y\in L\mid y<x\}$ has $\alpha$ elements for all (or many) $x$.
Notice that the density character of $X'$ in the weak-* topology can be smaller than $\mathrm{dens}(X)$.
A second and much more general question is: If $X$ is a topological vector space and $\dim(X)=\alpha$ (where $\alpha$ is an infinite cardinal), is there a chain $L$ with $\alpha$ closed subspaces of $X$?
A positive answer to the second question settles the whole question, but the first seems much more accessible (and maybe is the only one with a positive answer). And, since that is the case I am most interested in, I choose to enunciate the problem in the particular case.
I would be grateful for partial answers or even examples (except in reflexive Banach spaces or with density character at most $\mathfrak c$).
EDIT: I realized that this is possibly undecidable in ZFC. But I'm okay with adding axioms such as the Choice Hypothesis and the Generalized Choice Hypothesis. I am most interested in positive results, even if it's necessary to add new axioms. But negative results would be interesting too.

Note that for a Banach space $X$, the $\subset$-poset of all $w^$ closed linear subspaces of $X^$ is isomorphic with the $\supset$-poset of all norm closed linear subspaces of $X$, via the map $Y\mapsto Y_\perp$, inverse to $Z\mapsto Z^\perp$.

So the question is equivalent to  the analogous  for  closed linear subspaces of $X$
